# How can I fake a class with templated methods without recompiling?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to fake (i.e. swap with a testing implementation) a class like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
   ...
   template <typename T> void Bar(T& baz);
   ...
}
```

Currently, I achieve this by making an unrelated class with the same interface:

```
class FakeFoo {
public:
   ...
   template <typename T> void Bar(T& baz);
   ...
}
```

And swapping the class used throughout the codebase via a macro:

```
#ifdef USE_FAKE_FOO
using ClientFoo = FakeFoo;
#else
using ClientFoo = Foo;
#endif
```

The issues with this is that I am required to re-compile the codebase depending on whether or not I want to run tests. Even worse, when I have multiple `FakeFoo`s which implement different functionality for different tests, I have to re-compile the codebase for each specific `FakeFoo` I wish to use.

Is there any way I can work around this?

NOTE: templating the code that uses a Foo does work, but I don't want to require that all client code does this just so tests can be more easily run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't do it with templated code.

C++ needs to compile everything before you get your executable. "Later" modifications without a recompile is not possible. If you have a defined interface you can exchange libraries against testing  ones, but never with a templated interface if the types for the calls are different.

So you have to indirect your call via some kind of library call but that will not work with different template instances.

If it is ok for you to link again without compilation, you can also use two times the same names and signature for function calls an exchange the files you link together. But this would also work only if your code uses the same interface for the calls which did not work with you templated code.